# mongoose Get Unexpected function expression

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Why my Code Get: `[eslint] Unexpected function expression. (prefer-arrow-callback)` ?

**Code:**

```
 kitty.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('a');
    }
  });
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have eslint configured to take arrow functions when they're inline like that. Try this:

```
kitty.save((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('a')
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can disable this eslint rule, whether inline or in your eslintrc file. E.g.

```
// eslint-disable prefer-arrow-callback
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('a');
  }
});
```

You can read a bit more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions%20here). And about eslint rules [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/).

Comment: I'm using node.js, and mongoose, is better to use arrow function?

Comment: You could. No big impact either way, and what some consider "modern" javascript, ES2015+, writes a lot of arrow functions.